# Is control theory of any use in the Infosec disciplines?

Tags: theory

I'm currently studying Engineering in a European university (not CEng, though), and I've always been fascinated by the network security/information security field.

As far as I know, crypto is the most math-heavy specialization out there, but it typically uses abstract algebra and number theory. What about other fields, such as probability or control theory?

My control systems textbook quoted some applications of control theory to congestion control of Web servers, but didn't elaborate much further.

Is there any application of control theory to information security?

Comment: Hi A. Darwin, this reads like a [career question](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1165/29640)

Comment: Should I move this question to the Workplace?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this site, you might take a look at their help and try to find similar question to see if it and how will fit there. In any case you should avoid to ask the same question on different SE sites.

Comment: Probably off-topic, but I'll throw you a bone anyway. Advanced mathematics is useful because it helps you *think* of different problems, and gives you a broad perspective. Math is useful when you need to find security flaws in anything having to do with math.

Comment: If you rephrase it as 'what's the use of disciplines ABC&D in infosec', it may even be on topic here. And the answer is 'not much'. As you've noticed, discrete maths is used in crypto. Probability theory is kosher, though.

Comment: Nominating for re-opening since control theory was used at least once by a high-proficiency APT to wreak havoc on real-life equipment.

Comment: Control theory is used by NTP (as least the 'canonical' implementation ntpd) and some security mechanisms depend (though not that precisely) on time, e.g. the 'Delorean' attack on HSTS